# Getting all the dates in a month that do not coincide with a project's dates

Tags: php, datetime

I'm creating an array of dates that won't be selectable in a calendar. The following works, although the way I've gone about it is quite long-winded.

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of getting all the dates in a month, where dates don't fall on various days a project does run on. It's probably more clear from the example...

```
$project_days_this_month = []; 
$month_array = [];

$month = date('n'); 
$year = date('Y'); 

$project_days = [1, 6]; // days of week the project runs on
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);     

// create an array of days in month
for ($day = 1; $day <= $days_in_month; $day++) {
  $date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day; //format date
  $month_array[] = $date;
}

// get project days in month
foreach ($project_days as $pd) {
  //loop through all days
  for ($day = 1; $day <= $days_in_month; $day++) {

    $date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day; //format date
    $day_number_of_week = date('N', strtotime($date)); 

    // add project days to array
    if($day_number_of_week == $pd){
        $project_days_this_month[] = $date;
    }

  }
}

// get the difference - these will be non project days  
$non_project_days = array_diff($month_array, $project_days_this_month);
print_r($non_project_days);
```

Are there any PHP functions that can be used here that would might make this code more concise?

Comment: Not really a code review type of question and can't really review when the pertinent code for `cal_days_in_month()` is not shown.  You should familiarize yourself with PHP's  `DateTime`, `DatePeriod`, `DateInterval`, etc. classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt to make this code as clean as possible.
Note that i have not changed almost any of the logic you provided.

```
<?php

class ProjectDays {
    private $projectDays;

    public function __construct(array $projectDays, $month, $year) {
        $this->projectDays = $projectDays;
        $this->month = $month;
        $this->year = $year;
    }

    public function getNonProjectDays() {
        $monthDays = array();
        $projectDays = array();
        $daysInMonth = $this->getDaysInMonth();
        foreach ($this->projectDays as $projectDay) {
            for ($day = 1; $day <= $daysInMonth; $day++) {
                $date = $this->formatDate($day);
                $monthDays[$day] = $date;
                $weekDay = $this->getWeekDay($date);
                if($weekDay == $projectDay){
                    $projectDays[] = $date;
                }
            }
        }
        return array_diff($monthDays, $projectDays);
    }

    private function getWeekDay($date) {
        return date('N', strtotime($date));
    }

    private function getDaysInMonth() {
        return cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $this->month, $this->year);
    }

    private function formatDate($day) {
        return "{$this->year}-{$this->month}-{$day}";
    }
}

$excludedDays = new ProjectDays([1, 6], date('n'), date('Y'));

print_r($excludedDays->getNonProjectDays());
```

Comment: It's beautiful , but can I ask, what is the purpose of `$day` in `$monthDays[$day] = $date;`? Wouldn't it work with `$monthDays[] = $date;` especially since the array index starts with 1 in the for loop, and not 0.

Comment: for loop is inside foreach, `$monthDays[] = $date;` would not work.